# Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

I created a table in MySQL:

'object_label' with columns 'id' and 'name'.
I inserted values to this table.

In java I created new class -'ObjectLabel':

```
import javax.persistence.*;

 @Entity
    @Table(name = "object_label")
    public class ObjectLabel  implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3475812350796110403L;
        private String name;

        public Long getId() { return id; }

        @Id 
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(precision = 10, unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

        /**
         * @return the name
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        /**
         * @param name the name to set
         */
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


    }
```

in hibernate.cfg.xml defined:

```
<mapping class="com.myCompany.model.ObjectLabel" />
```

I whant to get the valuse from the table,
I definded service :

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    @Transactional( readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS )
    public Collection<T> findAll() {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        return 
            session.createCriteria( persistentClass 
                    ).setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
                            ).list();
    }
```

I gets empty list.

in the database 'select * from 'object_label''  return the values)

what the problem in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `persistentClass` is in your code but a Criteria Query to retrieve  `ObjectLabel` instances for all records would look like:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(ObjectLabel.class).list();
```

Not sure why you're using `Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` since you're not doing any projection.

To see what is happening exactly, I recommend to activate the logging of SQL statements (either using the `hibernate.show_sql` property as suggested by nkr1pt or via the `org.hibernate.SQL` logging category). From the Hibernate documentation:

> #### [3.5 Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)
>
> ...
>
> When developing applications with
>   Hibernate, you should almost always
>   work with `debug` enabled for the
>   category `org.hibernate.SQL`, or,
>   alternatively, the property
>   `hibernate.show_sql` enabled.

Comment: I'm working with debug enabled, but I don't get any information on my mistake.

Comment: @Rivki You should at least get the SQL query that Hibernate is performing. So what SQL query do you see? How does it differ from the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

What is the sql that hibernate generates, you can see it in the console/log if show_sql in config is set to true.

Also, use @Entity(name="...") instead of @Entity @Table(name="...."),
you're mixing JPA annotations with Hibernate annotations

Comment: No, `@Table(name="....")` and `@Entity(name="...")` are not the same thing. And the former is not Hibernate specific.

Comment: I edited the question, add inserted the import. now you can see that I use EJB annotation.